# Redundant webgl calls in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have multiple meshes rendered using three.js. When I used the webgl inspector to trace the webgl calls, I saw a lot of redundant uniform variable calls (Ambient color, point light color, view matrix, normal matrix, etc). Yet these uniforms stay constant in one frame for my scene.

Is there a way to eliminate these redundant calls other than merging the meshes into one?

Comment: can you post your code so give a better outlook?